# operator<< and stringstream overloading in c++

Tags: c++

### **Problem:**

From overloaded `operator<<`, `cout` will only print first bit:``"Hello guys, "`, while the stream is multiple shifts` << "Hello guys, " << "I can't get here!" << str << "\n"`.

My question is, why I only get the first bit of stream?

### **Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
class Debug {
private:
    std::stringstream stream;
public:
    std::string str() const{
        return stream.str();
    }
    std::stringstream& operator<<(std::string &s) {
        stream << s;
        std::cout << s;
        return stream;
    }
    std::stringstream& operator<<(const char s[]) {
        stream << s;
        std::cout << s;
        return stream;
    }
};
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Debug &d) {
    output << d.str();
    return output;
}
int main() {
    Debug debug;
    std::string str("Bad input");
    debug << "Hello guys, " << "I can't get here!" << str << "\n";
    std::cout <<"\n\n"<< debug;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to [debug](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) that code, it becomes pretty clear why it behaves like that (Hint: one of your `operator<<()`definitions is hit only once).

Comment: It's clear to you that your first `<<` operator is going to return a `std::stringstream` and any further calls to `<<` are being called on that, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, why I only get the first bit of stream?

as it was mentioned in the comments, any further calls after the 1st one of the `Debug::operator<<()` overload, will go to the overloaded operator of `std::stringstream` because you return a reference to that one.

What you probably want is a class that wraps a `std::ostream` interface like follows:

```
class Debug {
    std::ostream& os_;
public:
    Debug(std::ostream& os) : os_(os) {}
    template<typename T>
    Debug& operator<<(T val) {
       // Intercept whatever you want to intercept here ...
       os_ << val;
       return *this;
    }
};
```

This will ensure that the `Debug::operator<<()` overload is called repeatedly when the statement

```
    debug << "Hello guys, " << "I can't get here!" << str << "\n";
```

is going to be executed.

---

```
int main() {
    Debug debug(std::cout);
    std::string str("Bad input");
    debug << "Hello guys, " << "I can't get here!" << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hello guys, I can't get here!Bad input
```

See the [**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baecee3f3710eaa6).

---

To collect the stuff at an inner stream, and just output the contents at a certain point, you can do it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class Debug {
    std::ostringstream os_;
public:
    template<typename T>
    Debug& operator<<(T val) {
       os_ << val;
       return *this;
    }

    // Overload the operator<< to output the buffered stuff
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Debug& debug) {
        os << debug.os_.str();
        return os;
    }
};


int main() {
    Debug debug;
    std::string str("Bad input");
    debug << "Hello guys, " << "I can't get here!" << str << "\n";
    std::cout << debug;
    return 0;
}
```

Another [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86ccf2ba52605ae7).